# VBA XMLHTTP request : not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to save the oHttp.responseText to a file and receive an error :

> Run-time error '-2147024882 (8007000e)': Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Here is my code :

```
Dim oHttp As Object
'Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Call oHttp.Open("GET", url, False)
    oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode("Username" + ":" + "Password")
Call oHttp.Send("")

Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2
fsT.Charset = "utf-8"
fsT.Open
fsT.WriteText oHttp.ResponseText //<--- HERE IS THE ISSUE
fsT.SaveToFile outputFile, 2

fsT.Close
Set fsT = Nothing
Set oHttp = Nothing
```

Are there any solutions out there that **don't involve** increasing your memory or adding hardware. 
For example, is there a way to parse the responseText to receive smaller bits of it?
Should I open the response in a browser? Browsers don't seem to hit any memory limits even if the response is too large.

Note : I can't seem to be able to access the `responseText` property. Even this causes the same error message :

```
Dim result as String
result = LEFT(oHttp.responseText, 100)
```

Note2 : the responseText is only 72MB and I have 8GB of RAM

Comment: have you tried assigning to a `Variant` instead of a string?

Comment: Yes I tried, doesn't solve the issue. It doesn't seem to come from storing the responseText in a file or variable. The issue comes from not being able to access the responseText property. Otherwise, I would have been able to parse it.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `Call` keywords - they're not needed and you're accessing an object's method, not calling a routine. Also, get rid of the parentheses and quotes `("")` after the `.Send` method of the `oHttp` object - this is asking it to evaluate a blank string. I'll be surprised if that stops the error - but won't hurt to try.

Comment: Why not write the responseText directly to a file?  I'm not seeing any benefit to running it through the Stream object...

Comment: The stream is not important and is not causing the issue. It is the oHttp.responseText that is not accessible because of not enough storage